# Can I atattch sensors and bluetooth chips with my L293D DC Motor Drive Shield using my Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, servo

I plan on creating a RC car using arduino. I need a motor drive shield to connect my 2 9v DC motors and a 5v Servo motor, and I want to know if I can use a L293D DC Motor Drive Shield with a bluetooth module (HC-12 module) and an ultrasonic sensor.

Comment: Hello! This question would be more on-topic on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Try asking there.

Comment: Oh thank you! Oops

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to this LD293D shield: http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=L293D_Motor_Driver_Shield.

Here are a few considerations for your required setup.

**Pin Requirements**

1. 4 digital pins are required to interface with 74HC595 shift register while 2 PWM pins to control the 2 DC motors.
2. 1 PWM pin to control the servo motor.
3. 2 digital pins to interface with the ultrasonic sensor. (you can use digital pins 2 and 13 which are not being used by the LD293 shield).
4. UART TX/RX pins to connect to the HC-12 module.

So in total, 6 digital and 3 PWM pins are required which should be available.

**Power requirements**

1. The DC motors can be powered via the external 9V power supply. Make sure each motor current doesn't exceed 600mA. Also wary of the power selector jumper on the shield. More info on that [here](https://lastminuteengineers.com/l293d-motor-driver-shield-arduino-tutorial/).
2. The servo motor is powered from the VCC pin of Arduino while using the shield so you need to be careful. The absolute max current limit of the VCC pin is 200mA so make sure not to exceed it. These ratings are specified [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/67094)
3. The HC-12 module requires a recommended 200mA power supply so connecting both servo and HC-12 to VCC pin of Arduino is out of the question. Ultimately, you'll have to power either or both servo and HC-12 from a separate supply.